# spring kafka offset increment even auto commit offset is set to false

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am trying to implement `manual offset commit` for the messages received on `kafka`. I have set the offset commit to `false`, but the offset value keeps on increasing.

Not sure what is the reason. Need help resolving the issue.

Below is the code

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: kafka-consumer-sample
  resources:
    cache:
      period: 60m

kafka:
      bootstrapServers: localhost:9092
      options:
        enable:
          auto:
            commit: false
```

KafkaConfig.java

```
@Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapServers);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        config.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config);
    }

 @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }
```

KafkaConsumer.java

```
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka-consumer.topics}'.split(',')}", groupId = "${kafka-consumer.groupId}")
    public void consume(ConsumerRecord<String, String> record) {

        System.out.println("Consumed Kafka Record: " + record);
        record.timestampType();
        System.out.println("record.timestamp() = " + record.timestamp());
        System.out.println("***********************************");
        System.out.println(record.timestamp());
        System.out.println("record.key() = " + record.key());
        System.out.println("Consumed String Message : " + record.value());
    }
}
```

output is as follows

```
Consumed Kafka Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = test, partition = 0, offset = 31, CreateTime = 1573570989565, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 2, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = 10)
record.timestamp() = 1573570989565
***********************************
1573570989565
record.key() = null
Consumed String Message : 10
Consumed Kafka Record: ConsumerRecord(topic = test, partition = 0, offset = 32, CreateTime = 1573570991535, serialized key size = -1, serialized value size = 2, headers = RecordHeaders(headers = [], isReadOnly = false), key = null, value = 11)
record.timestamp() = 1573570991535
***********************************
1573570991535
record.key() = null
Consumed String Message : 11
```

Properties are as follows.

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 100000000
auto.offset.reset = earliest
bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
check.crcs = true
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
enable.auto.commit = false
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = mygroup
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
```

This is after I restart the consumer. I expected the earlier data to be printed as well.

Is my Understanding correct?
Please Note I am restarting my springboot app expecting the messages to start from first. and my kafka server and zookeeper are not terminated.

Comment: I am not using the poll() method. Also even though the offset will increase automatically for every subsequent poll, it is not happening in server partition. And how to solve this problem :(

Comment: Okay can you show the kafka container config?

Comment: There is no other configuration apart from what i have already provided :( . Can you specify what you are looking for so that I can check from my side

Comment: @Deadpool I have updated my Question with the code for Creating ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.

Comment: try my answer @Tushar Banne

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the`auto` acknowledgement is disabled by using this property `ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG`, Then you have to set the acknowledgement mode on container level to `MANUAL` and don't commit the `offset` because by default it is set to `BATCH.`

```
@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.AckMode.MANUAL);
    return factory;
}
```

Because when auto acknowledgement is disabled [container](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ContainerProperties.html#setAckMode-org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties.AckMode-) level acknowledgement is set to `BATCH`

> public void setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode ackMode)

Set the ack mode to use when auto ack (in the configuration properties) is false.

1. RECORD: Ack after each record has been passed to the listener.
2. BATCH: Ack after each batch of records received from the consumer has been passed to the listener
3. TIME: Ack after this number of milliseconds; (should be greater than #setPollTimeout(long) pollTimeout.
4. COUNT: Ack after at least this number of records have been received
5. MANUAL: Listener is responsible for acking - use a AcknowledgingMessageListener.

**Parameters:**

> ackMode - the ContainerProperties.AckMode; default BATCH.

[Committing Offsets](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#committing-offsets)

> Several options are provided for committing offsets. If the enable.auto.commit consumer property is true, Kafka auto-commits the offsets according to its configuration. **If it is false, the containers support several AckMode settings (described in the next list). The default AckMode is BATCH.** Starting with version 2.3, the framework sets enable.auto.commit to false unless explicitly set in the configuration. Previously, the Kafka default (true) was used if the property was not set.

And if you want to read from the beginning always you have to set this property `auto.offset.reset` to `earliest`

```
config.put(ConsumerConfig. AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
```

**Note :** Make sure `groupId` must be the new one which does not have any offset in kafka

Comment: I made the change you told. Started the consumer. sent messages from 11 to 20. 
stopped the service and started again. sent a 21. My expectation was to get the message from 11 to 20 again. but i did not i got 21 :(

Comment: set that config `AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG` to `earliest` @TusharBanne

Comment: No Still the same. offset keeps on increasing.Updating the post with latest properties that get printed on the console.

Comment: try changing the consumer group `groupId = "${kafka-consumer.groupId}` to some other new group @TusharBanne I doubt you are using the older consumer group, just set it to `groupId = "test"`

Comment: Yup.. If I change the group Id, it printed all the messages again. So whats the issue here?

Comment: but the problem is i dont want the offset to be comitted for that consumer group. If my application goes down. I cant change the group id to retrive the messages.

Comment: It Worked after I disabled the auto commit interval. thanks for your help.
 config.put(ConsumerConfig. AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 100000000);